# What is the name of the song playing in Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood in episode 6 at 9:40?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

What is the name of the song playing in *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood* in episode 6 at 9:40 ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the song playing in that scene is [Entr'acte](https://youtu.be/jJqk-olK2mI).